# Uploading to MS SQL from Dataflow runs fine with DirectRunner but not DataflowRunner (using pyodbc / msodbcsql18)

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-dataflow, pyodbc

We're trying to use Dataflow for uploading data from BigQuery to a Microsoft SQL server. We use Dataflow flex environment where I've installed pyodbc and msodbcsql18.

When running our Dataflow script using DirectRunner inside the docker container in an interactive session we have no problem: BigQuery is read, data are transformed and finally uploaded to the SQL server.

However, when running the same script using DataflowRunner in an interactive session we get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 267, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 340, in <lambda> 
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 581, in do_instruction
    getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 618, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 996, in process_bundle
    element.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 221, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 346, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 348, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 707, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 708, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1200, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1281, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1198, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 843, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mssql.py", line 30, in process
    connection = mssql_client.connect(host, database, userid, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mssql_client.py", line 5, in connect
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.Error: ("01000 [while running 'Upload to SQL server in 10 threads-ptransform-22']", "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.1.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

We see the same error when deploying the image/template to our GCP project. A google search on the error message shows that it's a fairly common problem and there are different solutions. But it works in DirectRunner but not in DataflowRunner, so is it because the code is run on a different worker (which for some reason doesn't have libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.1.1 installed) and not on the image that we've created with the Dockerfile below? Is it the executing user that doesn't proper file permission?

Our Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base:20220418_RC00

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY transfer.py .
COPY mssql_client.py .

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/transfer.py"

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN pip install -U apache-beam==2.39.0
RUN pip install -U pyodbc==4.0.34

# Install dependency for apt-key
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
# Install Microsoft SQL ODBC (dependency for pyodbc)
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
```

The mssql_client.py:

```
# File mssql_client.py
import pyodbc

def connect(host, database, userid, password):
    connection_string = 'DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.1.1};SERVER='+host+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+userid+';PWD='+password
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    return connection
```

We've also tried to set the `DRIVER` parameter to `{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}`.

We don't have a requirements.txt but use setuptools instead:

```
# File setup.py 

import setuptools

setuptools.setup (
   name='setup',
   version='1.0.0',
   install_requires=[ 'pyodbc' ],
   packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

I've also tried adding 'msodbcsql18' in `install_requires` but then the job just hangs forever.

Comment: Hi @OnionJack, The issue seems to be that the path could not be found. Can you please check the path of the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was almost onto something with my question

> But it works in DirectRunner but not in DataflowRunner, so is it because the code is run on a different worker (which for some reason doesn't have libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.1.1 installed) and not on the image that we've created with the Dockerfile below?

It appears that the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#create_and_build_a_container_image) explicitly says that only requirements.txt dependencies are available for the Beam containers:

> As part of the Dockerfile, you need to install apache-beam to generate the job graph. Note that the Flex Template container built using the Dockerfile is used only to create a job graph and start the Dataflow job. The packages installed in Flex Template containers are not available in the Beam container.

> For packages to be part of the Beam container, you must specify them as part of the requirements.txt file. Ensure that you do not specify apache-beam as part of the requirements.txt file. The Beam container already has apache-beam.

Since I needed msodbcsql18 which is only available through the apt repository I then looked a bit more into [customizing Beam containers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments).

I finally got it ro work by customizing the base container as such:

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.39.0

RUN apt-get update -y

# Install various dependencies for pyodbc
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

RUN pip install -U pyodbc==4.0.34
```

Make sure that the base image that you're using contains the same Python and Dataflow version, in my case I used v3.7 and 2.39 respectively (check out the `FROM` and `pip install apache-beam` in the Dockerfile in the original post).

Then once you've built and pushed your image to your docker repository, add an additional argument `sdk_container_image` to start your pipeline with DataflowRunner:

```
--runner=DataflowRunner --sdk_container_image=[your-image-name]
```